# Can anyone check my schematic?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I want to make a relay control module with an ESP32. Can anyone check my schematic?

[image]

Comment: R2 is redundant.

Comment: @winny, R2 is needed, not redundant. Before the ESP32 is powered up and run software to configure GPIO, that pin will be a hi-Z input. R2 ensures that Q1 is off during that time.

Comment: @TonyM How much current will it leak into the base in Hi-Z-mode?

Comment: BJT itself pulls harder than 10k

Comment: What is the thing supposed to do and with what specs? If these are not known we can't say if the device can do what is required and if it does within specifications.

Comment: @Justme, It's supposed to control an electrical device remotely with the help of an esp32. It takes 230V ac input and converts it to 5v dc for relay control and 3.3v dc for esp32. I added a spring terminal for taking input from a conventional household switch as well. I added the SW1 to reset the esp32. TX and RX pins for programming the esp32. And added the CN2 to take external input from a temperature sensor or anything like that. The model of the relay is SRD-05VDC SL-C. Please give some suggestions for improvement... **Sorry, for my English.

Comment: You will need to be careful with the pcb layout using that relay. You will need slots in the pcb in order to get adequate creepage distance between the mains and the coil pads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all looks good. To clarify the comments, \$R_{2}\$ is needed to maintain off condition if the SIG1 pin is in High-Z mode.

R3 should work most of the time. The relay coil requires 90mA. The lowest current gain (from the datasheet) at \$I_{C}=50mA\$ is \$h_{FE}=64\$. So the max base current is 1.4mA. At \$I_{C}=90mA\$, \$V_{BE}\$ is about 0.8V. So:

$$R_{3}<\frac{3.3-0.8}{.0014}=1.78\text{k}\Omega \approx 1.5\text{k}\Omega$$
is a better value.

Answer (score 1):

R2 is needed for the reasons stated in the [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638581/can-anyone-check-my-schematic/638582?noredirect=1#comment1692176_638581) from [TonyM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/115257/tonym) above.

> Before the ESP32 is powered up and run software to configure GPIO, that pin will be a hi-Z input. R2 ensures that Q1 is off during that time.

R3 is borderline. You will have about 1.3 mA into the base of your transistor will need a gain of at least 54. A transistor is a current control device. Your relay needs about 70mA to operate so the load current divided by gain gives you the base current needed. I design with a gain of 10 for hard and 20 for soft turn on.

You could substitute a 2N7000 MOSFET and no  circuit changes would be needed. The MOSFET is a voltage controlled device and needs a minimum voltage from source to gate to turn on but only requires enough current to overcome the miller capacitance of the gate. You would need to check the brand you purchase there differences in VGS and some of the older ones will not work. If you use an avalanche rated MOSFET D1 could be eliminated. Check to be sure SIG1 can be low during reset. Other then that it looks great.